# Error trying to pass in variables when calling MSI file

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am **very** new to using Powershell but keen to learn.

I am attempting to install a MSI package, using PowerShell and passing in some variables. The end result is for this to be an unattended installation deployed via Jenkins using PowerShell. Please keep in mind I have changed the port numbers for this example:

```
msiexec /i /quiet $SYSTEMID ="PC01" $PORT1 =0000 $PORT2 =0001 $TARGETDIR ="C:\Application\" "C:\MSIPackage64bit.msi"
```

When trying to run the above I get presented with a Windows ® Installer. pop up which lists a load of MSIExec variable options.

I have been looking on the web for quite some time and now believe I'm having issues due to my lack of understanding when it comes to PowerShell.

Comment: What is the command supposed to look like without the variables? Does it work when you manually substitute the values in?

Comment: Powershell variables are not at all the same thing as MSI Public Properties. Answe arco444's question please but I suspect that you want to be setting public properties for the MSI which is a different syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/I needs to be followed by the path to the MSI to be installed.  Also get rid of the $ in front of the property names.  Finally TARGETDIR isn't always TARGETDIR.  Some MSIs are authored as INSTALLDIR, INSTALLLOCATION and other possible directory table entry names. Adding logging ( /l*v path_to_log ) is usually a good choice also.

PS- Please note that since you are doing a silent installation you need to either be installer per-user without need for elevation or you need to already be elevated.

Comment: Thank you for helping I had some issues adding logging but then was able to via;

 /log C:\MSIInstaller.log